# Confusion with solartime R package

Tags: r, posixct

I am trying to calculate solar position for my location in western Sydney, Australia.  I'm using the function "computeSunPosition" through the 'solartime' package, however I think I’m doing something wrong.  The output variables look wrong.  For instance, azimuth never reaches 0 on any day and the shape of time of day vs azimuth graph looks like a sharp “V” rather than a smoothed “U”.

The DateTime is POSIXct with tz = UTC, however I’m in Sydney, Australia.  The hour, elevation, declination and azimuth were created through the computeSunPosition function.  Please see below the script I used to create the data frame.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
latdeg<--33.611627
longdeg<-150.745147

NewDat<-as.data.frame(C3$DateTime)
colnames(NewDat)<-c("DateTime")
sunposition<-as.data.frame(computeSunPosition(timestamp = NewDat$DateTime,latDeg = latdeg,longDeg = longdeg))
sunposition$DateTime<-NewDat$DateTime
 
head(NewDat)
DateTime
1 2019-04-04 00:00:00
2 2019-04-04 00:05:00
3 2019-04-04 00:10:00
4 2019-04-04 00:15:00
5 2019-04-04 00:20:00
6 2019-04-04 00:25:00

head(sunposition)
hour declination elevation   azimuth            DateTime
1  9.992404  0.08814259 0.7326991 0.7373197 2019-04-04 00:00:00
2 10.075738  0.08814259 0.7447492 0.7128573 2019-04-04 00:05:00
3 10.159071  0.08814259 0.7564591 0.6878219 2019-04-04 00:10:00
4 10.242404  0.08814259 0.7678135 0.6622048 2019-04-04 00:15:00
5 10.325738  0.08814259 0.7787966 0.6359992 2019-04-04 00:20:00
6 10.409071  0.08814259 0.7893922 0.6092001 2019-04-04 00:25:00
```